# SQL Dependency Tracking Not Working

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am having some issues with SQL dependency tracking. On some of our developer machines SQL dependencies are recorded as expected, on some they are not. We cannot locate the setting on the machine that is preventing the SQL dependency from being tracked. When the same code and configuration is run on our UAT and Production machines we get the same issue, no SQL dependency tracking.

It seems to be machine or user specific. Is there a permission, firewall or some other such setting that may be preventing the SQL dependency tracking from working within certain environments?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are some devs building / running against .NET 4.5 and some .NET 4.6?

if you are using .NET 4.6+, you get more dependency tracking "for free", but on 4.5 and earlier you need to use Status Monitor to turn on additional profiling to get sql dependencies collection at runtime.

The instructions for installing status monitor are here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies/